# In Extjs is there a way to remove the bar marking color in 3d bar charts when there is no data?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

[image: Sample Image]

My problem here is, even when there is no data for 'Calls connected' (see the bottom legends), blue color is showing in the 3d bar chart.
How can i remove a color when there is no data  assigned to that?

I'm using Extjs 6.0.2, series 3d bar chart (Prior to the document -> http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.chart.series.Bar3D.html)

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a filter to the store so the zero values are not included in the filtered data that is passed to the chart:

```
filters: [
  function(rec) {
    return rec.data.calls > 0;
  }
],
```

See fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1iro